# React-Native Expo AuthSession oAuth2 Google Logout

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, expo

I'm trying to log out of google with expo authsession, but it always returns the error message: Failed to revoke token: *RevokeTokenRequest requires a valid token to revoke*. I've already tried to put Bearer ${google_access_token} and ${google_access_token} but without success.

```js
  //LOGOUT GOOGLE
  const handleLogoutGoogle = async () => {
    let config = {
      issuer: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/logout",
      scopes: ["openid", "profile"],
      /* This is the CLIENT_ID generated from a Firebase project */
      clientId: "cccccccccc-aio1fviva82o78umts2k4uvsn1val515.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    };
    const google_access_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@myApp:googleAccessToken");
    if (google_access_token) {
      console.log(`Bearer ${google_access_token}`);
      try {
        await AuthSession.revokeAsync(config, {
          token: `${google_access_token}`,
          isClientIdProvided: true,
        });
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@myApp:googleAccessToken");
        return null;
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Failed to revoke token: ${e.message}`);
      }
    }
  };
  //LOGOUT GOOGLE
```

Comment: Hey Edi! Did you mange to sear through this?

Comment: Hi man! No, I can't

Comment: Have you tried integrating Firebase with auth session?

Comment: In fact, I couldn't even implement Google login with Expo to work properly

Comment: So no authentication flow worked with expo-auth-session?

Comment: No dude, not yet. You got it?

Comment: Hi man, I managed to log out and posted my answer

Answer (score 2):

I can log out as follows: At login time, I store the token in localStorage and in the logout method, I did as follows:

```html
//LOGOUT GOOGLE
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@ellot:googleAccessToken");
    if (token) {
      try {
        await AuthSession.revokeAsync({ token }, { revocationEndpoint: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke' });
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@my:googleAccessToken");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERROR XXX', error)
      }
    }
    //LOGOUT GOOGLE
```